# bottom 0 in IE for all screen size

Tags: html, css

I want my svg images to be on bottom of my block (position:absolute, bottom:0). But in Internet Explorer it doesn't work (displays in the center). I can set width and height to svg and it will work somehow, but it will broke on another device with smaller/bigger screen size. How can I resolve this problem? Thank you!
Here is the code [codepen](https://codepen.io/Youfka/pen/aqbwBv)

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 150px 20px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.main {
  background-color: #000;
  line-height: 48px;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text">Some text here</div>
    <button>click</button>
  </div>
  <svg class="left" fill="#fff" viewBox="0 0 1300 150" width="50%">
    <polygon points="0,0 0,150 1300,150"></polygon>
    </svg>
  <svg class="right" fill="#fff" viewBox="0 0 1300 150" width="50%">
    <polygon points="1300,0 0,150 1300,150"></polygon>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it necessary to make it in SVG ?

Comment: not necessary svg

Comment: Have some courtesy and mark the answers as accepted or no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same with using either simple divs or with pseudo elements. The following is an example I created to demonstrate both approaches.

https://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/oEYYob

The example uses `position` along with `border` to set the bottom design the way your want. You can use the div solution if you want to place images in it or use the pseudo solution if only want to show arrow cut in the design at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a background image, why not use a `background-image`??

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 150px 20px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.main {
  background-color: #000;
  line-height: 48px;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg viewBox="0 0 52 3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="0,0 26,3 52,0 52,3 0,3" fill="#fff" /></svg>');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text">Some text here</div>
    <button>click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using CSS alone.

We can make triangle shape in CSS. Stick a triangle at the bottom of your main container. Will give the same effect.

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 110px 20px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.main {
  background-color: #000;
  line-height: 48px;
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
}
.arrow-down {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 500px solid transparent;
  border-right: 500px solid transparent;
  
  border-top: 50px solid #000;
  position:absolute; 
  bottom:-50px;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.left {
  left:0;
}
.right {
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text">Some text here</div>
    <button>click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-down">
  </div>
</div>
```